# Change color onClick than change back when clicking other item

Tags: javascript, html

I have my Javascript set-up so when I click a button the text changes color, I'm trying to make the text change back to its original color when clicking another button.

HTML:

```
    <button class="middleHeader" id="button1">Button 1</button>

    <button class="middleHeader" id="button2">Button 2</button>
```

JS:

```
    var button1 = document.querySelector('button1'),
        button2 = document.querySelector('button2');

    function changeColor() {
        this.style.color = '#5d98fb';
        return false;
    }

    button1.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
    button2.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
```

Comment: So do the code accordingly! You have not written anything to make that happen :)

Comment: @Rayon I know I would after to do an if/else statement but I don't know how I would write that.

Comment: If you make the colour a class, it’s easier to remove; define some CSS `.selected { color: #5d98fb; }`, then use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add and remove the `selected` class. (Hint: remove it from both `button1` and `button2` before adding it to `this`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should have different handler functions for both the buttons

OR

- Have `if` condition in handler function

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1'),
  button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');//ID selector starts with "#"

function changeColor() {
  this.style.color = '#5d98fb';
  return false;
}

function restoreColor() {
  button1.style.color = '';
  return false;
}

button1.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
button2.addEventListener('click', restoreColor, false);
```

```html
<button class="middleHeader" id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="middleHeader" id="button2">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions. The first one:

```
var button3 = document.querySelector('button3');
button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.style.color = '#ff0000';
     return false;
}, false);
```

If you want to change the color by a click anywhere outside the buttons then the next one could solve your problem:

```
document.window.addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.style.color = '#ff0000';
     return false;
}, false);
```

I don't try the two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1'),
  button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

function changeColor() {
  this.style.color = '#5d9345';
  return false;
}



button1.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
button2.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
```

```html
<button class="middleHeader" id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="middleHeader" id="button2">Button 2</button>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p id="text">This text will change style</p><br>
 <button type="button" onclick="javascripot:changeStyle();">Click me</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascripot:changeStyle1();">Click me</button>
 <script>

    function changeStyle() {
   x = document.getElementById("text");
    x.style.color = 'blue';
    }
        function changeStyle1() {
   x = document.getElementById("text");
   x.style.color = 'black';
  }
   </script>
```